# quoting questions

Tags: support, markdown

I want to utilize the `` sign to show an other font `other font` sometimes this works and sometime not see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/71287) the contrast between the last Q and the firsts.

 Can someone help me to master this?

Comment: The source of that answer is **really** hard to read with all the HTML mixed in with markdown. Everything that you have done with HTML tags can also be done with markdown. That would probably make things easier. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @Daniel I will learn this thank you for this important link.

Comment: @Daniel thanks to you I discover that markdown is an indipendent language. When you write an answer, the side bar shows basic htlm, so I was sure that the basic language of the post is hlml.